# Do I need terms and conditions and privacy policy on my website

Tags: internet, terms-of-service

I have made my own website with a simple blog and login facilities so users can play a simple game I have made. Do I need terms and conditions and a privacy policy? I have already implemented a cookie banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question to ask is, if someone takes your game, or part of your website and then uses it in a way you would see as wrong, would you be okay with that?

If the answer is yes, then Yes you need a terms and conditions, even if it is basic.

also in terms of your "log in" feature do these people provide any details, including their IP address that they would see as not wanting to be shared?
Yet again, if the answer is yes, then you need a privacy policy to either say you have no privacy here, or you will not share their details with anyone.

The old adage, It's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you have suggestions on how to make/get/whatever them?

Comment: jamieking.co.uk/resources/free_sample_privacy_policy.html

www.seqlegal.com/free-legal-documents/website-terms-and-conditions